# OpenJump Print layout

Tags: printing, openjump

How to print a layout in OpenJump?
I would like to print vector layers of an area toghether with map legend and a graphic scale indicator, to a pdf .
I tried the Jump Printer Plugin v1.87, but the results are very bad:

- low res
- useless configuration: size of cartographic elements do not adapt to the zoomed area. When you save a Cfg with a legend, the next time, if you are not at the same zoom level as the time you saved the Cfg, the legend will be too big or too small (and even far away from the map you are trying to print)
- source code unknown

I would accept even a Python solution

Comment: What kind of layers do you use (rasters, vectors, WMS)? Please tell more about the useless configuration, I did not quite understand your need. Source code is probably here https://sourceforge.net/p/jump-pilot/code/HEAD/tree/plug-ins/CadPlan_JumpPrinter/.

Comment: Source code path looks correct and there is even a manual  https://sourceforge.net/p/jump-pilot/code/HEAD/tree/plug-ins/CadPlan_JumpPrinter/doc/OpenJUMP_Printer_Guide.pdf

Comment: Ok, thanks for the answer. I added details in the post

Answer (score 1):

It seems that the plugin saves the cartographic elements at fixed scale that is relational to the scale of the map and if you zoom on the map the elements get smaller or bigger. Obviously the writer of the plugin has had printing series of maps at fixed scale in their mind. User cannot change the behavior.

I do not feel that the resolution of pdf is poor but I made only a simple test with some manually digitized polygons and the default renderer (ISA). Sample of your data might help to evaluate the resolution.

Source code of the printer plugin is at https://sourceforge.net/p/jump-pilot/code/HEAD/tree/plug-ins/CadPlan_JumpPrinter/ and there has been some activity around the plugin during the last few weeks. Feel free to write mail to the OpenJUMP mailing list and if you are a Java developer the project would certainly be happy to get you to join the team.